# Unable to debug using remote java application

Tags: java

I am running a java application and i am trying it to debug some code. I am running the application in debug mode and i am getting the msg also 'Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:30303', transport: 'socket' . Still i am not able to debug. I am using JDK6 and IntelliJ.
 Response will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the command line and the options used in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you need the following system properties: `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=30303,server=y,suspend=y`

`suspend=y` will make the java process to suspend at start-up and wait till you connect with the debugger.